# Speed Up Self Hosted Wordpress Website

Tags: performance, wordpress, hp-proliant, windows-server-2019, iis-10

I have a DL360 G8 rack server, and I decided to self host my website on it, (on a virtual machine of course). The server itself is pretty kitted out, with dual xeons, Raid 0 drives, and 32 GB Ram (6GB Allocated to the VM). The Server is running Windows Server 2019, so is the VM hosting the site. It used to have a load time of about 5 seconds, but recently it has been going as high as 30s. I checked the plugins, they aren't the issue. I also installed a caching plugin, which did next to nothing. I use Cloudflare DNS, with all my A and CNAME records proxied through cloudflare. When I checked the speed on pingdom.com, it showed that a massive amount of time was spent "Waiting", which it described as the browser waiting for the server to deliver data. How can I speed up my site? Again, I understand that using a hosting service may be faster, but my site was working just fine before, so please don't say that.

EDIT: Results from webpagetest.org:
https://webpagetest.org/result/210226_Di3Y_801c04c6f14d2c9241699f7a9f643255/

Comment: It's hard to say specifically without knowing more precisely what "waiting" means. You'll need to research further to determine exactly where the server OS is spending that time.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to even begin to guess. You should check your system to see where the bottleneck may be, do [general WordPress performance optimizations](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/199/18054), etc., first.

Comment: Do you have any tips for finding out what is going on with the server? I assume it's a network thing. I have a fast asus router/modem if that helps

Comment: Start by checking your system's CPU, disk and network usage. Being a Linux admin I can't really give you the specifics of _how_ that's done on Windows, but that's the place you need to start.

Comment: Wordpress is usually hosted on Linux and most Wordpress information talks about Linux hosting. 6 seconds is pretty slow already. Check your CPU usage, I suspect PHP usage very high but caching plugin properly configured should mitigate that. Please use webpagetest.org to run a test and put the results in your question